# requireFilesDontExist - Maven Plugin - How to?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-enforcer-plugin

I'm trying to fail the maven build when certain files are present anywhere in build path.

Looking at enforcer plugin: [requireFilesDontExist](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireFilesDontExist.html). But we need to know absolute file path for it to work.

How to use it (or create new) when i have only file names and it can be anywhere in build path?

Comment: First I would ask which kind of files are those? Why do you have only file names instead of filename and location? Furthermore you can write your own enforcer rule if needed (https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html)

Comment: Thanks. Those are some configuration files for application. Micro service Developer can put it anywhere in build path. If not given by developer then common repository is used. Actually developer should remove its local configuration before deploying. The plugin will aid in this.

Comment: Sounds very strange trying to solve a problem with Maven does not make sense on that level. and of what kind of configuration we are talking about? Give a full example what you are trying to solve etc. otherwise it's even hard to give a good suggestion...

Comment: Sorry!! can't disclose much as it is a company internal idea.